faculty final interview
I had a full day faculty interview, after three weeks i requested a follow up to department chair he replied this" I hope you are having a good week. I'll be in touch within the next week or so to let you know of our decision. We are currently reviewing applicants and should make a decision in the next few days. Thank you and all the best." what should i expect? since then one week passed no reply. Is this a rejection?

It means what it says, no more and no less. Do not try to read the tea leaves. More details in the linked thread

Where are the threads ?? I mean links?

It is not a rejection. There is no point in not making a rejection known past a self-imposed deadline.
Usually, a number of candidates are invited to campus. Schedules are difficult to make as the candidate needs to meet with a variety of people, so it could be that a single candidate is invited per week.
After all the interviews are done, a decision is made on the order of applicants, the cut-off, and then the applicants above the cut-off are contacted in order. The first one in this order receives an offer with the request to make a decision soon. If the first one does not accept the offer, then the offer goes to the second one, etc. Often, people who receive an offer might have other offers or are waiting for an offer from a more favorite place.
In effect, you have to expect for some time before you know whether you will get an offer or not. Unfortunately, if you are deemed acceptable, but are ranked low, e.g. they would take you but you are not the favorite candidate, they want tell you this because you might go away before they get to you, in which case they might not end up filling the position. Not filling a position is not a catastrophe, but it is quite bad.

Good answer.  Similarly, I'd explicitly point out that you can feel free to apply for, interview for, and potentially take other jobs if they don't make you an offer.  I've had industry experience and sometimes some of the job offers I got came in late so it's clear I wasn't the first choice.  However, it was good for me to be able to take such offers, because often one needs some job!

Thankyou so much! I agree
